# How to Save Color with QColordialog in Qt C++

Tags: savechanges

Can someone help with this problem,I am using the QColorDialog in QT c++ ad can't figure out how to save the selected color so it would be the same color after an app is shutdown and then restarted. I have included my slot here if it would help, the app work fine as long as you shut it off and restart it.

void MainWindow::on_actionBackGround_Color_triggered()

{
QColor color=QColorDialog::getColor(color);

```
      if (color.isValid()) {
          setPalette(QPalette(color));
```

{

{

Thanks for and help,it's been awhile.

Comment: You need to persistently store that value somewhere, i.e. in a file, and load it on program startup

Comment: Thanks for the help,I was thinking that but haven't tried as yet.